# Asterisk as a value input?

Tags: enumitem

I saw this code in a latex template:

```
% An itemize-style list with little space between items
\newenvironment{innerlist}[1][\enskip\textbullet]%
        {\begin{itemize}[#1,leftmargin=*,parsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]}
        {\end{itemize}}
```

I was wondering what "leftmargin=*" means. Forgive me if this question has been asked. The asterisk makes searching for an answer difficult.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). The asterisk means the width of the current label.  So if the label is `\arabic` the it is the width of `0`, if it is `\roman` then it is the width of `viii`, if the label is `\alph`, the width is set to the width of `m`.

Comment: It's in the enumitem package, so `texdoc enumitem` will show the documentation, then on page 4 there is a heading `leftmargin=*`  you don't really have to search the entire internet for `*` ;-)